# C++ does not import class methods from DLL while importing functions works fine

Tags: class, visual-c++, dll, linker

I am trying to import a DLL to my program. I am using the [__declspec( dllimport )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute. The problem is I get the linker error "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ...". This question has already been around here several times. But my problem is different.

I believe I have all the things set up correctly (header provided, lib-file with the exports linked in ...). When I try call a classic function (with or without extern "C" block) from that DLL, all works fine. The problem are just the classes.

All the method are exported within the DLL - I verified this by using the Dependency Walker.

Can there be some mismatch between the mangled exported names and the ones the linker tries to find? Or some other naming based problem? It seems there is no similar problem documented over the internet.

**EDIT**

The dependency walker sees the method

```
?LoadFile@CTxtFileHelper@@QAE_NPAVCWrapperFile@@I@Z
```

which is unmangled

```
bool CTxtFileHelper::LoadFile(class CWrapperFile *,unsigned int)
```

while the linker is trying to load the

```
?LoadFile@CTxtFileHelper@@QAE_NPAVCWrapperFile@io@mylib@@I@Z
```

which represents according to linker error message

```
__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall CTxtFileHelper::LoadFile(class mylib::io::CWrapperFile *,unsigned int)
```

The only difference is the namespace. Can it be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mark the classes with `__declspec(dllexport)` (or use a macro to do the dllexport/dllimport)?

Comment: Classes are exported. I manually checked that with the Dependecy Walker.

Comment: Is there a difference between the name the linker claims it can't find, and the name Dependency Walker claims is exported? Can you show an example of both these names, as well as the declaration of the corresponding function?

Comment: It seems you have placed `#include` directive for the library's header inside a namespace. Don't do that. `::CTxtFileHelper` and `mylib::io::CTxtFileHelper` are two different, completely unrelated classes. You've implemented one but are trying to use the other.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, the namespaces are the cause.